# Arduino Nano: MAX30102 and memory problems

Tags: arduino-nano, sensors

We are making a simple pulse oximeter device with an Arduino Nano and a [MAX30102](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX30102.pdf) sensor.

The problem is the SpO<sub>2</sub> reading and processing algorithm of the MAX30102 library literally does signal processing on the Arduino with large arrays of data and because of that, when you do BPM and SpO<sub>2</sub>, the 2kb memory of the Arduino is already full.

Can you guys give me some advice to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you mean large lookup tables / reference data, you should say, because that's definitely something worth knowing.  More details in any case.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work with just that library, or are you saying there are other libraries *also* that make it not work (like an OLED library)?

Comment: I meant the arrays that saves data. It takes 4 second of data and process it. That beginning data alone takes 400 bytes of 2k. And it hits %90 of 2kb at spo2,bpm and oled but i still need to add bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino UNO is not recommended for MAX30102 as it requires a lot of processing and RAM. Consider shifting to Arduino Mega or the ESP32.

Comment: In the question they acknowledge the library they're using uses a lot of ram. I think the question is how do they do it on their hardware *despite* that.  If it's fundamentally not doable in less ram, then explaining that might be useful.